# Proof of uniqueness of zero for this norm

Tags: proof-verification, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed vector space and $W$ a closed subspace of $V$. It is possible to define a norm on $V/W$ (the quotient space) by defining $\|v + W \|_{V/W} = \inf_{w \in W} \|v + w\|$. As an exercise I tried to prove that

$ \|v + W \|_{V/W} = 0$  $\iff$   $v \in W$ (iff $v + W = 0 + W$)

Could anyone please check my proof?

Proof:

$\Longleftarrow$: Assume $v \in W$. Then $-v \in W$ and hence $\inf_{w \in W}\|v+w\|= \|v-v\|=0$.

$\implies$: Assume $\|v + W\|_{V/W} = \inf_{w \in W}\|v+w\|= 0$. By the definition of $\inf$ there exists a sequence $w_n \in W$ converging to $-v$. Because $W$ is assumed to be closed it follows that the limit $-v$ is in $W$. But then $v \in W$ which means that $v + W = 0 + W$.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Closedness is vital here

Comment: aren't the arrows inverted in the proof?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini You are right! I will correct it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is absolutely correct.

Comment: Thank you for checking my proof! Thank you very much!!